# Not sure how to correctly split string and print out with variables in R

Tags: r, split, output, character

I'm trying to read a log file of NASA data line by line and then split into 5 columns. But right now it seems not splitting correctly, and another problem is that there is no common splliting characters.

```
fileName <- 'C:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/access_log_Jul95.txt'        
fileConn<-file('C:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/output.txt')                
conn <- file(fileName,open="r")
linn <-readLines(conn)
fo00:00:12 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/video/livevideo.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 0
```

This is the output I want:

```
199.72.81.55, [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400], GET, /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0, 200, 6245
```

Comment: Please share a few (or all) lines of the input file. Without the starting file, we have no idea what went wrong.

Comment: @abdou sorry I labed it wrong, it should be input

Comment: What would the desired output data frame look like in the example above?

Comment: @thepule just posted it

Comment: @abdou hey sorry I updated new info

Comment: @JonathanTian, that looks better. The answers below should help with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression `( - - |(?<=]) |(?<=\\") |(?<=\\d) (?=\\d))` for split:

```
lines <- readLines(conn)
do.call(rbind, 
  lapply(lines, function(line) strsplit(line, '( - - |(?<=]) |(?<=\\") |(?<=\\d) (?=\\d))', perl = T)[[1]]))

#      [,1]                   [,2]                           [,3]                                                               [,4]  [,5]  
# [1,] "199.72.81.55"         "[01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400]" "\"GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0\""                                "200" "6245"
# [2,] "unicomp6.unicomp.net" "[01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400]" "\"GET /shuttle/countdown/ HTTP/1.0\""                             "200" "3985"
# [3,] "199.120.110.21"       "[01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400]" "\"GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/mission-sts-73.html HTTP/1.0\""    "200" "4085"
# [4,] "burger.letters.com"   "[01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400]" "\"GET /shuttle/countdown/liftoff.html HTTP/1.0\""                 "304" "0"   
# [5,] "199.120.110.21"       "[01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400]" "\"GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/sts-73-patch-small.gif HTTP/1.0\"" "200" "4179"
# [6,] "burger.letters.com"   "[01/Jul/1995:00:00:12 -0400]" "\"GET /images/NASA-logosmall.gif HTTP/1.0\""                      "304" "0"   
# [7,] "burger.letters.com"   "[01/Jul/1995:00:00:12 -0400]" "\"GET /shuttle/countdown/video/livevideo.gif HTTP/1.0\""          "200" "0"
```

Answer (score 2):

Not as elegant as @Psidom solution, but this does the job:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

   df <- str_split(linn, " ") %>% 
        do.call(rbind, .) %>% 
        as.data.frame() %>%
        mutate(V6 = str_replace(df$V6, '"', ""),
               V8 = str_replace(df$V8, '"', ""),
               a = paste(V4, V5),
               b = paste0(V7, V8)) %>%
        select(c(1, 11, 6, 12, 9, 10))
# Clean up the column names
names(df) <- paste0("V", seq_along(1:ncol(df)))
```

Output:

```
                    V1                           V2  V3                                                      V4  V5   V6
1         199.72.81.55 [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] GET                                /history/apollo/HTTP/1.0 200 6245
2 unicomp6.unicomp.net [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] GET                             /shuttle/countdown/HTTP/1.0 200 3985
3       199.120.110.21 [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] GET    /shuttle/missions/sts-73/mission-sts-73.htmlHTTP/1.0 200 4085
4   burger.letters.com [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400] GET                 /shuttle/countdown/liftoff.htmlHTTP/1.0 304    0
5       199.120.110.21 [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400] GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/sts-73-patch-small.gifHTTP/1.0 200 4179
6   burger.letters.com [01/Jul/1995:00:00:12 -0400] GET                      /images/NASA-logosmall.gifHTTP/1.0 304    0
7   burger.letters.com [01/Jul/1995:00:00:12 -0400] GET          /shuttle/countdown/video/livevideo.gifHTTP/1.0 200    0
```

Comment: Good option.  Plus one.